# How do I get the right amount of change to the slope for my linear regression?

Tags: java, processing, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I want to program a linear regression with Processing. But I got mixed up which parameters I have to multiply and then add or subtract from my slope.

I have tried to change the parameters (make them negative, change the learning rate). The b does actually work, but I have got some problems to get the slope the right way.

```java
//Data
float[] P1 = {100,100};
float[] P2 = {200,300};
float[] P3 = {300,250};

float[][] allData = {P1,P2,P3};

//random start values
float w1 = random(0,3);
float b = random(-100,100);

float learningRate = 0.01;
int i = 0;

void setup(){
    size(1000,1000);
}

void draw(){
    background(255);
    axes();

    //Draw Points
    for(int j=0;j<allData.length;j+=1){
    float[] point = allData[j];
        advancedPoint(point[0],point[1],color(181, 16, 32),10);
    }

    //Gradient descend, thats the confusing part...
    if(i<10000){
        i += 1;
        float dcost_dreg = 0;
        float dcost_dtar = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<allData.length;j+=1){
            float[] point = allData[j];
            float yTarget = point[1];
            float yRegression = w1*point[0] + b;
            dcost_dreg += -2*(yRegression-yTarget);  //I don't understand these lines
            dcost_dtar += -2*(yRegression-yTarget)*point[0];
        }
        w1 += learningRate * (dcost_dtar/allData.length); 
        b +=  learningRate * (dcost_dreg/allData.length) ;//until here
    }

    //Draw Regression
    linearPoints(w1, b);
}

void linearPoints (float w1, float b){
    float y;
    for(float x=-width; x<width; x=x+0.25){
        y = w1*x + b;
        strokeWeight(3);
        stroke(100,100);
        point(x+width/2, -y + height/2);
    }
}

void axes(){
    for(float a=0; a<height; a=a+0.25){
        strokeWeight(1);
        stroke(255,100,0);
        point(width/2,a);
    }
    for(float b=0; b<width; b=b+0.25){
        stroke(255,100,0);
        point(b,height/2);
    } 
}

void advancedPoint(float x,float y, color c, int size){
    strokeWeight(size);
    stroke(c);
    point(x+width/2,-y+height/2);
}
```

In theory the program should fit a linear regression through my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear regression is base on the equation of a [Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#On_the_Cartesian_plane) in the form

> ```
> y = w1 * x + b
> ```

The terms

> ```
> dcost_dreg += -2*(yRegression-yTarget); 
> dcost_dtar += -2*(yRegression-yTarget)*point[0];
> ```

should calculate the error of the line equation in compare to the sample points, but your calculation is wrong.

The constant error (*`b`* error) is the difference of the sample y coordinate and the y coordinate which is calculated by the line equation on the sample x coordinate.
The linear error (*`w1`* error) is calculated by the gradient difference. The gradient difference is the quotient of a height and a width (y/x) rather than a product.
This means the calculation has to be:

```java
dcost_dreg += (yTarget-yRegression);
dcost_dtar += (yTarget-yRegression)/point[0];
```

The expressions

> ```
> w1 += learningRate * (dcost_dtar/allData.length);
> b  += learningRate * (dcost_dreg/allData.length);
> ```

Calculate the average error of the samples and apply the correction to the line equation by considering the learning rate.

Change the function `draw` to solve the issue:

[image]

```java
void draw(){
    background(255);
    axes();

    //Draw Points
    for(int j=0;j<allData.length;j+=1){
        float[] point = allData[j];
        advancedPoint(point[0],point[1],color(181, 16, 32),10);
    }

    //Gradient descend, thats the confusing part...
    if(i<10000){
        i += 1;
        float dcost_dreg = 0;
        float dcost_dtar = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<allData.length;j+=1){
            float[] point = allData[j];
            float yTarget = point[1];
            float yRegression = w1*point[0] + b;
            dcost_dreg += (yTarget-yRegression);
            dcost_dtar += (yTarget-yRegression)/point[0];
        }
        w1 += learningRate * (dcost_dtar/allData.length); 
        b  += learningRate * (dcost_dreg/allData.length);
    }

    //Draw Regression
    linearPoints(w1, b);
}
```

---

By the way, recommend to use [`line()`](https://processing.org/reference/line_.html) for drawing the axis and the current line equation:

```java
void linearPoints (float w1, float b){
    strokeWeight(3);
    stroke(100,100,255);
    float x0 = -width;
    float x1 = width;
    float y0 = x0 * w1 + b;
    float y1 = x1 * w1 + b;
    line(x0+width/2, -y0+height/2, x1+width/2, -y1+height/2);
}

void axes(){
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(255,100,0);
    line(0,height/2, width, height/2);
    line(width/2, 0, width/2, height);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! @Rabbid76
I tried to do that, but it didn't work out... I used the points P1(100,100), P2(200,200) and P3(300,300). So I can clearly see if it works or not.

I also printed out the cost of my linear regression and first it seems to get smaller, but then it starts growing again. And my Linear Regression starts to turn over and get a negative slope.

Comment: @enwo02 I can't reproduce this. But you may try `dcost_dtar += (yTarget-yRegression + b)/point[0];`